# Higgs decay into baryon-antibaryon pair

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, higgs, baryons

I have an exercise for "Introduction to high energy physics" and I'm baffled. The exercise states:

**Problem:** Higgs particle of mass 125.7 GeV decays in an exclusive channel of baryon-antibaryon (sigma and anti-sigma):

- Draw a leading order quark diagram for this decay
- Find in PDG tables the mass of the $\Sigma^0$ baryon and calculate the energy of each of the jets produced in this decay.

**My issue:** Higgs doesn't seem to have a decay channel into baryon- antibaryon pair in all the resources I looked at. The closest I can get is $H \to b\bar b$ and $H \to c\bar c$ which would eventually create jets if I'm not mistaken. In all other cases, the Higgs decays into bosons or leptons...

Do you think it's a purely hypothetical exercise? Like, calculate things that won't happen? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: The exercise is asking to just draw the quark level diagram, so just the $H\to \bar q q $ part. The hadronization into baryons happens at a later time.

Comment: To add to the above hint, which of the quarks of the Σ does the Higgs couple the strongest to, so, then, decays to?

Comment: You have to remember that there are also strange quarks and not only bottom charm and top. see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/quark.html

Answer (score 0):

The actual Higgs decays are complicated by strong interactions of the quarks involved, but you are asked for a generic question, " if Higgs decays simply to Sigma-Sigma_bar what are the energy relations. This [Feynman diagram](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Feynman-diagram-describing-the-decay-H-t-t-with-one-t-subsequently-decaying_fig2_303921835) for tau antitau (the lepton) might make it clear (ignoring athe tau decay)

[image: higstau]

where the appropriate quark for sigmas takes the place of the tau , and the needed quarks to make  the sigma pair introduced.This last can be done by introducing two gluons radiated from the quark pairs going into quark-antiquark, that add up correctly to the quarks needed for sigmas.